# Get the contents of lambda

Tags: python

I define the following variables:

```
index = 1 
val = 0
```

I create the following function:

```
f = lambda a: a[index] == val
```

Later on, I would like to see the content. I would like to get the `index = 1` and the `val = 0`. I use `inspect.getsource(f)`. However, this gives me:

```
'f = lambda a: a[index] == val\n'
```

I was hoping to get the value of index and val.

Comment: The values aren't saved in the source code. They're in the environment, and change if you reassign the variables.

Comment: I think you should look at the lambda's code object's closure/cells internals. It may get tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could modify the output of lambda in order to save the three element you want (I mean here `val` , `index` , and `a[index] == val` .So, you could do the following :

```
index = 1 
val = 0
f = lambda a: (a[index] == val,index,val)
```

let's suppose that you give the function an argument `L` , then when you want to get the `val` you do `f(L)[2]`  and `index` is equal to `f(L)[1]`,then `val` is equal to `f(L)[0]`

Comment: But then the caller of the function needs to know it must only read the first value of the return value.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can do this (at least on Python 3.9):

```
def get_closure_values(f):
    return {
        name: cell.cell_contents
        for (name, cell) in zip(f.__code__.co_freevars, f.__closure__)
    }


def make_fun(index, val):
    return lambda a: a[index] == val


f = make_fun(index=84, val=99)
print(get_closure_values(f))
```

This prints out

```
{'index': 84, 'val': 99}
```

It does peek into interpreter internals, so it might break on you.